# Google Places API - Angular Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a service in which I get a list of sites and the ability to share that data between controllers

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('googleMapCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope ){

    var map;

    $scope.placeNameArr = [];
    console.log($scope.placeNameArr);


    function initialise (position) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){

            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
                center: center,
                zoom:12
            });

            var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(),
                new google.maps.LatLng());

            var option = {
                bounds: defaultBounds,
                types: ['(cities)']
            };

            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, option)   ;

            var request = {
                location: center,
                radius: 8047,
                types: [ 'restaurant' ]
                // 'restaurant'
            };  

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

        })


    }

    function callback(results, stattus) {
        if(stattus == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i]
                createMarker(results[i]);
                // console.log(results);
            }
             $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.places = results;
            });

        }
    }

     function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
         photos = place.photos;

        if (!photos) {
            return;

        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location


        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){

            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
             '<img src='+ place.photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 175, 'maxHeight': 175}) +'>' + '<br>' + 'Rating:' + place.rating + '<img src='+ place.photos +'>' + '</div>');
            infowindow.open(map,this);

        })
        console.log(place);
        $scope.placeNameArr.push(place.name);
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialise);
    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

}])
```

I I'm not sure what approach i should take in this problem.

Ultimately i would like to share this results with Wikipedia API Controller

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('wikiCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http ){
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.searchTermArr = [];
    vm.searchWiki = function(wikiFactory){
        console.log(response);
    }
    vm.searchWiki = function(){
        $http({
            url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + vm.searchTerm + '&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
            method: 'jsonp'
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            vm.searchTermArr.push(response[1]);
            vm.searchTermArr.push(response[2]);
            vm.searchTermArr.push(response[3]);
        });
    };

}]);
```

and get information based of long name of location ....

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I don't really know how to create service for google map to share it between my controllers ...

Comment: Did you check this answer, I think It did exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers